# Length of Longest Substring for String using HashSet

Tags: java, string, collections, set, hashset

I have got the code for the length of longest substring but i am not sure what the "else" part of the below code does. 
Also, what does the variable start here indicate??

```
while(start < i && s.charAt(start)!=c){
                set.remove(s.charAt(start));
                start++;
            }
            start++;
```

Full Code of Method:

```
public static int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    if(s==null || s.length()==0)
        return 0;

    HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();

    int max=0;

    int i=0;
    int start=0;
    while(i < s.length()){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(!set.contains(c)){
            set.add(c);
        }else{
            max = Math.max(max, set.size());

            while(start < i && s.charAt(start)!=c){
                set.remove(s.charAt(start));
                start++;
            }
            start++;
        }

        i++;
    } 

    max = Math.max(max, set.size());

    return max;
}
```

Comment: What defines the "longest substring"?

Comment: The Longest substring is the string which could be any string whose length of longest substring is to be verified :Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3.

Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", with the length of 1.

Comment: Based on those examples it sounds like "longest substring" is actually "count of unique characters in a string"

Comment: Thats true. Longest Substring with all unique charecters.

Comment: What should be the "longest substring" of "abcabcdab"? and Why?

Comment: 4; abcd, bcda, cdab are the longest substrings of unique characters; you have shown there can be multiple substrings which are all the longest length of unique characters

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks for the longest substring where each character in the substring is unique.  The question asks to describe what the else block does, as well as describe start.  To describe, consider the string ***abcdbfg***.

start = 0; // A pointer to the first character in a unique substring

1. Build up the set until there is a *duplicate letter*.  This occurs when you get to abcdb.  At this point, the set contains 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'. (max length=4).
2. At this point, you want record the max (4), and move the 'start' pointer past the first duplicated letter ('b').  You do this because what remains is a new possibility for a unique substring.  During this time, you remove the leading characters 'a', 'b'.  The set will now contain 'b', 'c', 'd', and start points to the 'c'.
3. You resume building on 'c', 'd', 'b', until you find another duplicated letter, and you repeat until the string is complete.  In this example, the string continues to 'cdbfg', and the answer is 5.